# Dynamically execute commands in MS Access 2003?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I develop and update around 100 or so MS Access DB's. Making minor changes can be troublesome. Mostly because forcing users to log out so I can change the network shared MDB is difficult. Is there anyway I could link the MDB to a SQL DB and on aan event check a particular field in a table and execute the contents as a VBA string. For instance 'DoCmd.Close()'?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the issue correctly.

But you can run custom code (or a Macro) which is fired after a record is updated:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211226(v=office.11).aspx

So, if you create a table and have DoCmd.Close() fired in this event, all databases will be closed when this table is updated (by you).

N.B. Any unsaved work from the users will be lost by doing this.